# Find the total instance hours in my Google Apps Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Where can I find the total front-end instance hours that I have used in my previous days? It seems I can only see today's total.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK the actual instance-hours numbers are not directly available, at least not in the developer console.

What you *might* find helpful would be the historical graph of the instance usage, for the last (up to) 30 days, which you'll find in the [Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine) after selecting the `Instances` display mode, the desired timescale and the billed instance estimate graph:

[image]

Hover the mouse cursor over the graph and the actual billed instance estimate value will be displayed below the graph and the corresponding date and time is displayed in the top right corner. Note that there is some noticeable delay in updating the values, tho.

The graph detail level depends on the selected timescale, the coarsest being ~2h (on the 30 days timescale), so if you need more than just a general idea about usage trending you'd need to take care of:

- averaging and/or integrating on a daily basis
- accounting for the free daily quotas
- accounting for instance class (I'm unsure if that's already taken into account or not)

You could also try the billing date export feature. From
[Export billing data to a file](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293835?hl=en):

> You can export your daily usage and cost estimates automatically to a
>   CSV or JSON file stored in a [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/index) bucket you
>   specify. You can then access the data via the Cloud Storage API, CLI
>   tool, or [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
>
> ...
>
> Alternatively, you can export detailed data to a Google BigQuery
>   dataset. For more information, see [Export billing data to
>   BigQuery](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7233314).

**Note:** I haven't actually tried this export feature. so I can't tell if the instance hours values are in there. There's also the still open [GAE issue 10716](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10716) which suggests GAE stats might not be included.

Comment: wow, the most thorough response I've ever received, great job.